# How to format date in react native without third party libraries

Tags: react-native

I want to display date as a string in react native.
And I am trying to use phone locale to format it according to that locale.

```
var dt = moment(this.state.dt).locale('en-us', localization).format('LL')
```

I can do this with moment but is there a way to do this with clean RN?

Answer (score 2):

You can do [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) which is provided with the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object of Javascript.